# How to list only the EC2 instances in a given CloudFormation stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

What can I use for `$QUERY` in the command below that meets the following criteria:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query $QUERY
```

1. Only prints instances with an `aws:cloudformation:stack-name` tag equal to `test-stack`.
2. Only prints the `InstanceId` property for each instance.
3. Doesn't resort to piping, `for` loops, or other shell fanciness.

Comment: @jeff-terrell-ph-d how did you integrate it into the CloudFormation platform?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few parameters to use here:

**Querying**

`--query` ([docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html#controlling-output-filter)) for retrieving only the `InstanceId`

**Filtering by stack-name tag**

`--filter` ([docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html#options)) for excluding the instances not tagged with the stack's name

> - **tag-key** - The key of a tag assigned to the resource. This filter is
>     independent of the tag-value filter. For example, if you use both the
>     filter "tag-key=Purpose" and the filter "tag-value=X", you get any
>     resources assigned both the tag key Purpose (regardless of what the
>     tag's value is), and the tag value X (regardless of what the tag's key
>     is). If you want to list only resources where Purpose is X, see the
>     tag :key =*value* filter.
> - **tag-value** - The value of a tag assigned to
>     the resource. This filter is independent of the tag-key filter.

**Formatting**

`--output` ([docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html#text-output)) for returning only the values you queried for (so no quotes or json/table fluff)

> The text format organizes the AWS CLI's output into tab-delimited
>   lines. It works well with traditional Unix text tools such as grep,
>   sed, and awk, as well as Windows PowerShell.

Using those parameters like this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \                                                     
    --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId[]" \                        
    --filters "Name=tag-key,Values=aws:cloudformation:stack-name" "Name=tag-value,Values=test-stack" \
    --output=text
```

Returns:

```
i-sd64f52a  i-das5d64a  i-sad56d4
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the best solution. Trying to do the relevant filtering with a JMESpath query was proving difficult, but `--filter` is a better approach.

Comment: Brilliant, this was exactly what I needed. The filters help entry is not quite as clear as it could be.

Comment: Actually this answer is wrong, it will list list all instances with a tag called aws:cloudformation:stack-name and a tag value (not necessarily aws:cloudformation:stack-name) test-stack.

Comment: The proper filter to use is: 
Name=tag:aws:cloudformation:stack-name,Values=test-stack